# Include directive doesn't find the path

Tags: makefile, windows-7, cygwin

I am trying to call a makefile from cygwin on windows 7, but I get the following error *"makefile:100: /cygdrive/c/second_makefile.mak: No such file or directory"*

The main makefile has an include directive on line 100 `include /cygdrive/C/second_makefile.mak`.

Command `cat /cygdrive/C/second_makefile.mak` from the same cygwin terminal prints the content of the file.

**What is the cause that main makefile can't include the second makefile?**

Make version - 3.81

Cygwin version - 2.9.0

Comment: very bad idea to put files in the disk root.

Comment: Additional: cygwin make is 4.2.1  so, are you mixing cygwin with not-cygwin make ?

Comment: Yes. That was the cause. With cygwin make works fine.